# Set and Connect to Debugging port undetected chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium, undetected-chromedriver

### This is my old code:

```py
# session initialiser
opt = Options();
opt.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=8989");
opt.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:\\chromedriver\\chromeProfile");
service_obj = Service("C:\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
driver = Chrome((service = service_obj), (options = opt));
```

```py
# realtime debugger
opt = Options()
opt.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "localhost:8989")
service_obj = Service('C:\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service_obj, options=opt)
```

### what i do with this:

1. initiate a browser with a static port number.
2. run a separate code to connect to the previous session.
3. With this i don't need to relaunch chrome instance every time i debug
4. with this i can fast forward the initial going to the page, navigate to desired location find element(need the debugger here) and debug my xpath or anything else fast.

### can't Do this with Undetected chromedriver:

1. can't set the custom port.
2. can't even connect with the port mentioned in the UC session.

### What I need:

1. A way to do the same(like my old code) with undetected chromedriver

### setup of uc

```py
options = uc.ChromeOptions()
# options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=50620")
options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "localhost:50620")
driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
print("working")
```

### output:

it is not connecting to the existing session by uc instead it lunching a new one.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

use the below code with module "undetected_chromedriver" can work the same as .add_experimental_option in selenium. although it will connect to the opened chrome, it will also open a new one, but it will still work on the targe remote connection chrome
"options = uc.ChromeOptions()
options.debugger_address = "127.0.0.1:1688"
driver = uc.Chrome(options=options, driver_executable_path=".\chromedriver.exe")"